# EF Core Code First, 2 Many to one relations of same object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I have 2 classes like with the following structure, Person has 2 many-one relations with SchoolClass:

```
public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<SchoolClass> SchoolClasses { get; set; }
        public List<SchoolClass> OldSchoolClasses { get; set; }
    }

    public class SchoolClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I can add ghostProps but can't change the classes.

When I make a migration for EFCore, it adds 2 different Person Id's to the SchoolClass table which I want to avoid.

I want to generate 2 many to many tables instead:

- PersonSchoolClasses Table
- OldPersonSchoolClasses Table

Is this possible with Fluent API?

Comment: To avoid duplicates the IDs have to be a primary key of SchoolClass.  So you have to add a primary key to the database that is being used for the app.

Comment: This is a Code first app, i want to force those 2 tables to exist instead of EFCore adding 2 id's to the Class table

Comment: You need [Key].  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?force_isolation=true&tabs=data-annotations

Comment: The id's are arleady defined as primary keys in my OnModelCreating, that's not the problem

Comment: You cannot add the same ID twice when you are using a primary key.  So there is a contradiction between you saying it is adding the id twice and it is already defined as a primary key.

Comment: It creates 2 collums for id's

Comment: Why is there two columns for Person ID?  That is the real issue.   One Person ID should be removed. Maybe one is lowercase and the other uppercase?  Check the model you see if you can figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try inheritance:

```cs
public class SchoolClass    // this could be abstract
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class NewSchoolClass : SchoolClass
{
}
public class OldSchoolClass : SchoolClass
{
}
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<NewSchoolClass> NewSchoolClasses { get; set; }
    public IList<OldSchoolClass> OldSchoolClasses { get; set; }
}
```

And in DbContext:

```
-DbSet<SchoolClass> SchoolClasses { get; set; }
+DbSet<OldSchoolClass> OldSchoolClasses { get; set; }
+DbSet<NewSchoolClass> NewSchoolClasses { get; set; }
```

Comment: The structure of my classes is the way it is supposed to be. (The actual classes are more complicated, this snippit is just an example)

Comment: It doesn't matter. If the old one and the new one share same properties, you just move all properties to base class and derive an old and a new.